# How to calculate sum with multiple conditions in power bi

Tags: powerbi

I would like to create a DAX formula with a IF statement.

my logic would be :

```
IF(column[1]= "sales" && column[2] ="chicago"; SUM('Table'[SalesAmount]);
IF(column[1]= "sales" && column[2] ="sanfranciso"; SUM('Table'[SalesAmount]);
IF(column[1]= "sales" && column[2] ="newyork"; SUM('Table'[SalesAmount]);
IF(column[1]= "sales" && column[2] ="hoston"; SUM('Table'[SalesAmount]);
```

So, i need to calculate sales by city. how can we write above logic in dax expression in power bi?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `CALCULATE` function with your conditions.
For example, let's use it to calculate the sales amount of `chicago`

```
chicago_sales_amount = CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[SalesAmount]);column[1]= "sales" && (column[2] = "chicago" || column[2] = "sanfranciso" || column[2] = "newyork" || column[2] = "hoston"))
```

This above expression will calculate the sum of sales, only for the rows that respect the given condition.

Now you can apply the same logic for the other condition's.

`CALCULATE` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/calculate-function-dax)

Comment: Thank you but how can we calculate for all the cities in same measure by not calculating for every single measure?

Comment: I updated my response, with the statement for all cities.

Comment: What about if column[2] has more than 16 locations and its time consuming to calculate sum of sales for each city using above conditions. Can't we use same measure to calculate for every location?

Comment: If you want to calculate for all cities on the column[2], do like the answer of aldert above. Otherwise, I would create another table with the cities that I want and relate it with `Table` so on this will allow you to calculate for each target city.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the sum by city but only want it when column[1] = "sales" you can summarize based on a filter:

```
SumByCity = 
VAR curCity = 'Table'[column[2]]
RETURN 
    CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[SalesAmount]), FILTER(curCity = 'Table'[column[2]] && 'Table'[column[1]]= "sales"))
```